# Freebase query for fetching triples created by a user

Tags: freebase, mql

What is the Freebase query for getting all the SPO triples(subject, predicate, object) created by a user within a span of time? The SPO triples may be deleted or not deleted at the current moment.
For example, I would want to fetch all the SPO triples created by \user\user1 between "2014-01-07" to "2014-01-09".